# UIButton inside CollectionView Cell won't trigger action, nothing works

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have three UIButtons inside a CollectionView Cell, the touch action won't get trigger when tapping the buttons. I tried few solutions, but nothing works for me.
This is what I have so far:

```
protocol PostCellDelegate {
    func handleDeletePost()
    func handleUpvotePost()
    func handleDownvotePost()
}

class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var delegate: PostCellDelegate?

    lazy var buttons = [self.deletePostBtn, self.upvotePostBtn, self.downvotePostBtn]

    @objc func handleDeletePost(){
        delegate?.handleDeletePost()
    }

    @objc func handleUpvotePost(){
        delegate?.handleUpvotePost()
    }

    @objc func handleDownvotePost(){
        delegate?.handleDownvotePost()
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard isUserInteractionEnabled else { return nil }
        guard !isHidden else { return nil }
        guard alpha >= 0.1 else { return nil }

        guard self.point(inside: point, with: event) else { return nil }

        for button in buttons {
            if button.point(inside: convert(point, to: button), with: event){
                return button
            }
        }
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }

}
```

In hitTest, It does get the button I want (each one of the buttons) and returns it, but the action won't trigger.

This is my HomeVC (CollectionViewController):

```
//MARK: Button handlers
extension HomeVC: PostCellDelegate {
    func handleUpvotePost() {
        print("TEST")

    }

    func handleDownvotePost() {
        print("TEST")

    }


    func handleDeletePost() {
        print("TEST")
    }
}
```

CellForItem:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.postTitle.text = post.title

    return cell
}
```

I just can't get the button tap to work at all. no matter what solution I tried, it won't trigger it's action.
Any ideas?

Comment: You need to set the delegate when you dequeue the cell, eg cell.delegate = self

Comment: Thanks, I will try again today, I notice now that I didn’t write it in the right place.

Comment: where you have added action to buttons?

Comment: In PostCell, setting them in CollectionVC works, but I will try what JonJ said again and see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate when you're creating the cell.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.postTitle.text = post.title
    cell.delegate = self  // You're missing this
    return cell
}
```